# Read XML metadata from ExifTool in C#

Tags: c#, xml, exiftool

This is my C# code that calls Exiftool to obtain the XML metadata of a file:

```
...
try
{
    // exiftool output in UTF8, use chcp 65001 in console
    string args = String.Format("-X &quot;{0}&quot;", file);
    ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo("exiftool.exe", args)
    {
        StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
    using (Process proc = new Process())
    {
        proc.StartInfo = pi;
        // read output and error in async mode
        proc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => stdout += e.Data;
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => stderr += e.Data;
        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        if (proc.WaitForExit(10000))
        {
            if (proc.ExitCode == 0)
            {
                xml.LoadXml(stdout); // can raise error!!!
            }
            else
            {
                stderr = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                throw new Exception(stderr);
            }
            proc.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            proc.Kill();
            throw new Exception("timeout");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

It can process more than a thousand files a day correctly and yet in some it produces this error indicating that the XML is not correctly closed.

> ERROR. Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: rdf:Description, rdf:RDF. Line 1, position 7948.

Is there any other way to extract the metadata from a file in XML?

Comment: The xml files that are failing at not valid since some tags are not closed.  XML files should always be validated by the people who create the file(s) so users do not get errors.  In you case errors may occur if the connection is terminating prematurely or not all the xml file is being downloaded.

Comment: The output of exiftool is assumed to be valid xml.
The problem seems to be reading the output of the executable.
Thanks.

Comment: An XML: is not valid if the elements are not closed.  Thousand of files can be processed.  The problem is not the executable.